# Is there any reason to specify a x:Name in a Xamarin Forms XAML page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have XAML code that looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
    x:Class="Japanese.GettingStarted"
    x:Name="gettingStarted" 
    Title="Getting Started">
<ContentPage.Content>
```

My C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Japanese
{
    public partial class GettingStarted : ContentPage
    {
        public GettingStarted()
        {
```

The code works fine but I would like to know if there is any advantage or if it is normal to specify x:Name in the XAML?

Comment: for the Page element itself, not really.  You can always use the `this` keyword to get a reference if you need it.

Comment: as first comment, it doesn't really matter on the page. In fact the only time I can recall using a x:Name on a page element is when using a binding source with a x:Reference pointing to the root by it's name, which is an unusual edge case as normally you bind to viewmodels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are reasons. But if you haven't found them yet, you probably don't need it right now.

The most obvious reason is if you need to refer to it from your XAML. For example, you are working with data-binding and use a `ListView`. On the `ListView`, you use a simple `TextCell` which has context actions. The XAML could look like this (taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity#xaml) and tweaked a bit):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
         <ViewCell.ContextActions>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
         </ViewCell.ContextActions>
         <StackLayout Padding="15,0">
              <Label Text="{Binding title}" />
         </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now, if you have worked with data-binding before, you will know that the bindings of the `MenuItem`s in there are bound to each instance of the object that is in the `YourItems` collection.

But, it doesn't make sense to implement a delete command on an instance in that collection. You would want that on your view model. To do this, you will have to give your page a name, and refer to the command like this: `<MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyPage}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />` where `MyPage` would be the value you put in the `x:Name` attribute.

Other examples are probably out there, but this is a prominent one. If you do not have to refer to the page in any way, giving it a name add no real value.